# Missing test helper classes (e.g. RunAsFullyAuthenticatedRule) in mvn build

Tags: alfresco

I've been attempting to follow along with this blog post to create a test in the maven build - http://blogs.aca-it.be/blogs/-/blogs/alfresco-summit-part-5-%E2%80%93-developing-json-rest-services-with-webscripts - they use RunAsFullyAuthenticatedRule and ApplicationContextInit in their tests but in the standard maven build these do not resolve. Do I have to add something to the pom.xml in order to use these classes?

Comment: Which Alfresco artifacts did you define your program as depending on in your pom?

Comment: @Gagravarr I just used the AMP archetype with no modifications. Subsequently Mano (the author of the blog in question) furnished me with the modifications to the pom.xml to get the test helper classes to load.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the author of the blog.

" Those classes used to be packaged with the alfresco-repository dependency before 4.1.4. Add this dependency:"

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
      <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```